# How can I get position of an error in Oracle SQL query?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

How can I get position of an error in the query?

I need to get position in a query string which causes an error, like `sqlplus` does it:

```
SQL> insert into tbl (data) values('12345')
  2  /
insert into tbl (data) values('12345')
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12899: value too large for column "schmnm"."tbl"."data" (actual: 5,
maximum: 3)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I highly doubt you can. I'd try the debugger (or wireshark and look at the data on the wire) and see if anything else but the error text is returned from the server. If I had to guess that logic is in the oracle sqlplus client itself. Even if that isn't the case ... it's probably discarded below what's exposed via JDBC

Comment: There are two levels to determine the error in a query: syntax and data. Are you restricted to the data or do you need to check syntax too?

Comment: @Gamb, syntax is not much important, I check query before using it, however it may have runtime exceptions and I need to catch them and make a user friendly message.

Comment: @BrianRoach it is OCI client lib feature. In OCI an ErrorHandle is a vector of strings. So if sqlplus returns several lines of error message, each line is one field of this vector. For some unknown reason JDBC SQLException's error message contains only the 1st field of the vector. I think that the rest is silently discarded, there is no access to it. these error messages are really annoying when Oracle tells you that some constrain was violated, but will not tell you which one. The name of the constraint is usually in the 2nd field of the vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some ramblings when I almost lost hope, I found (thanks to correct search string in Google) following link: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1000551

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     c   INTEGER := DBMS_SQL.open_cursor ();
  3  BEGIN
  4     DBMS_SQL.parse (c, 'select * form dual', DBMS_SQL.native);
  5
  6     DBMS_SQL.close_cursor (c);
  7  EXCEPTION
  8     WHEN OTHERS THEN
  9        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Last Error: ' || DBMS_SQL.LAST_ERROR_POSITION ());
 10        DBMS_SQL.close_cursor (c);
 11        RAISE;
 12  END;
 13  /
Last Error: 9
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
ORA-06512: at line 11
```

Answer (score 3):

To expand on accepted answer I'll provide JDBC code necessary to retrieve error position from SQL query.

**PL/SQL:**

This PL/SQL block accepts sql query text and returns error position:

```
DECLARE
  c        INTEGER := DBMS_SQL.open_cursor();
  errorpos integer := -1;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    DBMS_SQL.parse(c, :sqltext, DBMS_SQL.native);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      errorpos := DBMS_SQL.LAST_ERROR_POSITION();
  END;
  :errorpos := errorpos;
  DBMS_SQL.close_cursor(c);
END;
```

It accepts two parameters `sqltext` and `errorpos`.

**Java:**

On Java side we need to call PL/SQL code from above and retrieve error position. Here's a method for that:

```
private int retrieveErrorPosition(Connection connection, String query) {
    CallableStatement callStatement = null;
    try {
        callStatement = connection.prepareCall(LAST_ERROR_POSITION_QUERY);
        callStatement.setString(1, query);
        callStatement.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.INTEGER);
        callStatement.execute();
        return callStatement.getInt(2);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "", ex);
    } finally {
        if (callStatement != null) {
            try {
                callStatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**Usage:**

Now, if query string executes with exception we can extract error position:

```
String query;
Connection connection;
try {
    //normal query execution
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    int sqlErrorPosition = retrieveErrorPosition(connection, query);
    //exception handling
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `SQLException` has additional fields that hold the SQL error number (as in `ORA-12899`) and a message something like what you see as `value too large for column "schmnm"."tbl"."data" (actual: 5, maximum: 3)`

You have to parse the string if you want to truely pinpoint the error in the SQL statement.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html

Read about the `errorCode` and `SQLState` properties within the exception.

Comment: That is so true, but it doesn't bother me so much when its generated by a stable sort of system like an Oracle database. When the Oracle version changes, you would have to watch for changes just to be vigilant.