# Can we find which table is causing ORA-00942 table or view does not exist.:

Tags: oracle, plsql, error-handling, dynamic-sql

I have a normal PLSQL block with CTAS query.

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE'
CREATE TABLE ZZZ_TEMP NOLOGGING PARALLEL AS
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(a,4) */
        *
    FROM
        HI0XXX001.HI_TABLE_NAME a
    LEFT JOIN
        HR_001_GROUP B
    ON
        a.EMPLOYERGROUP_UD =B.ACC_NUM
    LEFT JOIN
        HR_002_GROUP l
    ON
        a.EMPLOYERGROUP_UD =l.EMPLOYERGROUP_UD
    AND
        a.GRP_CON_UD_COV_CONTRACT_NAME=l.GRP_CON_UD_COV_CONTRACT_NAME
    ';
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN Dbms_Output.put_line(SQLERRM);
END;
```

Let's suppose HR_002_GROUP table does not exists in the schema where I am running this block. Is there any way to show error message that says HR_002_GROUP table does not exists?

The query I posted is just a sample scenario. We work in ETL structure and we have a large line of query script that inserts millions of data from one of many HI tables to another small table with prefix VH. I have around 15-30 tables in left join. It is time consuming to select each left joins to know which table is actually causing error.

Comment: Try `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK` instead of `SQLERRM`

Comment: That still won't tell you which table it's complaining about though.

Comment: Assuming that you have a variable that is used to create the SQL, why can't the error message simply not show the value of the variable?  Or you can use raise application error to raise a custom error and message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `DBMS_SQL` instead of native dynamic SQL, and then use `DBMS_SQL.LAST_ERROR_POSITION()` to identify the part of the statement with the error.

`DBMS_SQL` is less convenient than native dynamic SQL, but it's also more powerful.  There are several gotchas to watch out for.  The first one is that the procedure `DBMS_SQL.PARSE` does not only parse commands, it will automatically run DDL commands.

The below code tries to create a table using two other tables, one of which obviously doesn't exist.  A regular expression is used to output every character
 from the position of the error to the first whitespace.  (This code is based on [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17682718/409172))

```
declare
    v_cursor_id integer := dbms_sql.open_cursor ();
    v_sql varchar2(32767) := q'[
        create table zzz_temp as
        select *
        from dual
        join some_schema.fake_table
            on dual.dummy = fake_table.dummy
    ]';
begin
    dbms_sql.parse(v_cursor_id, v_sql, dbms_sql.native);
    dbms_sql.close_cursor(v_cursor_id);
exception
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line
        (
            sqlerrm||chr(10)||
            'Error occurred here: '||
            regexp_substr
            (
                srcstr   => v_sql,
                pattern  => '\w+',
                position => dbms_sql.last_error_position()
            )
        );
        dbms_sql.close_cursor(v_cursor_id);
end;
/
```

DBMS_OUTPUT:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
Error occurred here: fake_table
```

Some other random code suggestions:

1. Use `PARALLEL(4)` instead of `PARALLEL(A, 4)`.  Statement-level parallelism is almost always better than object-level parallelism.  If you run one table in parallel you'll probably want to run the whole query in parallel.
2. Try to avoid `WHEN OTHERS`.  Use a more specific error handler if possible.

Comment: Thank you this solves my problem a little bit. But i got the idea. Much appreciated.